# Bootstrap navbar loosing format in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I create a navbar where I display some text in the left side and right side. Everything works fine in computer, but when I run it in mobile, the text in the left side is not formatted.

Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #003366">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left: 20px;">
          <cfoutput>
          <font color="white"><h3><i>Company Name</i></h3></font>
          <font color="white" size="1">
              123 main St<br />
              Manager - Max<br />
              123.456.7890<br />
              test@email.com<br /><br />
          </font>
          </cfoutput>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <p style="margin-right: 50px;" align="right">
          <cfoutput>
          <font color="white" size="5"><i>00:00PM<br />Now</i></font>
          </cfoutput>
        </p>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

In the mobile, it displays:

```
   Company Name
   123 main St
   Manager - Max                  123.456.7890
test@email.com
```

The correct should be:

```
   Company Name
   123 main St
   Manager - Max                  
   123.456.7890
   test@email.com
```

Does anyone know why in the phone or table it is not formatted correct?

Thanks

Comment: When I put in your code, I don't see anything wrong with it.. However, you could try <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left: 20px; display:block;">

Comment: Hum... Did you try it using safari and iPhone? display block makes the phone number in new line, but it is not inserting the margin-left: 20px